# Returning BadRequest from WebApi Custom method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Using .net core web api here.

I have a endpoint in my api as:

```
[HttpPost("data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData(List<string> udata)
{
 JArray sets = new JArray();
 try
 {
    sets = Helper.GetData(udata);

 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
   return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
 }
}
```

In the above I am calling an custom method in my helper "GetData" which does all the processing and calculations. To make the Api controller clean I moved all the processing to this helper method.

Below is my helper class:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static BadRequestObjectResult GetMessage(string message)
    {
       return new BadRequestObjectResult(message);
    }

  public static JArray GetData(List<string> udata)
  {
      if(udata == null)
         return  GetMessage("Data is null");

      //do some processing and calclulations here
      //return BadRequest if some issue

   }
 }
```

If there is some processing issue or some of the data is not as intended or some other issue I want to throw BadRequest. For this I made a custom method to do so "BadRequestObjectResult".

Now my issue is, if there is an issue in GetData it doesnt throws back to my api or exits from my loop. It just continues to next statement.

I know there is some issue by the way I am returning this but not able to find the issue.

Can anyone point out the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Why do you want `GetData` to return a `JArray`? Just make it return `IActionResult`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto after processing and calculations I want to the GetData method to return an JArray which is the result expected by my angular ui

Comment: Emh... no, your Angular expects a JSON result, JArray is just a JSON.NET name. Just return `new JsonResult(yourData)` and done

Comment: Not strictly relevant to your question but also, is there a particular reason you've got this `GetMessage` method instead of just `return BadRequest("Data is null");`?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I wanted to keep my Api clean and move all the the processing code to common helper class. In my helper class method, if an error occurs I want to throw BadRequest which was not available in helper class as its not inherited from controllerbase. Because of this I created custom message method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is to throw an exception from your Helper class and and handle it from your PostData method. For example...

You could throw an ArgumentException and explicitly catch that from your API method.

```
public static class Helper
{

  public static JArray GetData(List<string> udata)
  {
      if(udata == null)
         throw new ArgumentException("Data is null");

      //do some processing and calclulations here
      //throw ArgumentException if there is an issue

   }
 } 

[HttpPost("data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData(List<string> udata)
{
 JArray sets = new JArray();
 try
 {
    sets = Helper.GetData(udata);
    return Ok(sets);
 }
 catch (ArgumentException e)
 {
   return BadRequest(e.Message);
 }
}
```

This way you can only worry about return codes from your controller while your Helper methods are only concerned with the input and aren't returning something specialized for a controller. It's a bit more flexible that way if you ever want to use your Helper class elsewhere.

This will also meet your requirement of stopping processing upon hitting a bad result, so as soon as a bad result is encountered the result set is thrown away and a BadRequest response is issued.

Comment: Thanks this works. One question though, should we raise an ArgumentException here or WebException. Since its an api what would be an appropriate exception.

Comment: Either class of exception would work but since the exception is raised on an argument to a method I would say that ArgumentException is the more descriptive choice in this instance.